# How to start firefox in safemode?

Tags: 14.04, firefox

How to start firefox in safemode using terminal,Because I don't see any `safemode` option for firefox in Ubuntu

Answer (score 10):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
firefox --safe-mode
```

Do not forget to close any Firefox instance before running this command.

---

[Refer to MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_mode) for more information.

Or show all options via

`firefox --help`

```
Usage: firefox [ options ... ] [URL]
       where options include:

X11 options
  --display=DISPLAY  X display to use
  --sync             Make X calls synchronous
  --g-fatal-warnings Make all warnings fatal

Firefox options
  -h or --help       Print this message.
  -v or --version    Print Firefox version.
  -P        Start with .
  --profile    Start with profile at .
  --migration        Start with migration wizard.
  --ProfileManager   Start with ProfileManager.
  --no-remote        Do not accept or send remote commands; implies --new-instance.
  --new-instance     Open new instance, not a new window in running instance.
  --UILocale  Start with  resources as UI Locale.
  --safe-mode        Disables extensions and themes for this session.
  --jsconsole        Open the Browser Console.
  --jsdebugger       Open the Browser Toolbox.
  --start-debugger-server [port|path] Start the debugger server on a TCP port or Unix domain socket path.  Defaults to TCP port 6000.
  --browser          Open a browser window.
  --new-window  Open  in a new window.
  --new-tab     Open  in a new tab.
  --private-window  Open  in a new private window.
  --preferences      Open Preferences dialog.
  --search     Search  with your default search engine.
  --recording  Record drawing for a given URL.
  --recording-output  Specify destination file for a drawing recording.
  --setDefaultBrowser Set this app as the default browser.

      -g or --debug          Start within debugger
      -d or --debugger       Specify debugger to start with (eg, gdb or valgrind)
      -a or --debugger-args  Specify arguments for debugger
```

Comment: was enough to let it fix itself, I just restarted w/o safemode and it worked again (with some extensions that got auto-disabled as I did nothing in safemode) thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can open Firefox in **safemode**, but you can't directly see the `safe mode` option.

1. Open Firefox.
2. Open the menu.
3. At the bottom of the menu you will see a **?** (help) - click on it.
4. Select `start with add-ons disabled`.

A pop-up appears.

[image: Imgur]

Click on <kbd>restart.</kbd>

Now another pop-up appears.

[image: Imgur]

Click on `start in safe mode`.

Answer (score 1):

Help > Troubleshoot Mode is the newer alias for "Safe Mode".

For more details on how to use Troubleshoot Mode, [refer to Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/diagnose-firefox-issues-using-troubleshoot-mode).

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while Firefox is starting. A dialog will appear with two buttons: *Start in Safe Mode* and *Refresh Firefox*.