# How to remove naganoadigei.com popup virus

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, malware, popup-ads

Whenever I click any URL so that will open a new tab with this URL (Please be careful):

```
hxxp://naganoadigei.com/imp/6932/?scontext_r=xlBO1OGoXtDY%2AqpCVwdK6hjcJXf8xQdE2bF9D7qYvJirlGAXcl42kf_7I6Zo60fY&md=snIhJiO2cDMywiIzJiOiEjNwADe5ADMiwiIiJiOiETN1cDe4AzNiwiIyJiOigGd0BnOv8SYwBnLzFmcrFmcpd3bytmLp52LkF2coJ2bhJHZvICLigmI6QzMyQDLiwmI6ISZu1SVTJCLiQnI60yMzADLionI6cTM2UDLismI6ETf
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried this with all my browsers such as Mozilla and Chrome; same thing happens in both browsers.

How do I remove this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using your home internet or something else? Are you using a proxy or VPN?

Comment: What's your DNS server settings?  Are you using your Home internet? Are you using a VPN?

Comment: I'm Using Home Internet no proxy no VPN

Comment: Everything is automatically obtained.

Comment: I would start by checking the browser's extras/extensions. If you find something you didn't installed there, remove them all.

Comment: Do you see such pop ups in other devices like phones connected to your network? If that's the case this is probably due to ISP injecting ads into your webpages.

Comment: no, that ads are visible only in desktop and not so frequently. and one more thing  I noticed a few days ago that mostly happen when I visit any non-SSL sites.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues on ubuntu 18.04 . Damn how did it manage to get in here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087450/how-to-remove-naganoadigei-com-popup-virus/1089365#comment1789174_1087450) is on the right track. There are a number of extensions that you can pick up than can cause this type of behaviour. Coupon Companion comes to mind but there are others as well. One way to determine if it's a plugin or extension causing this problem would be to launch the browser in safe mode:

[Firefox safe mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/677409/225694)

For Chrome use `chrome --disable-extensions` launched from the terminal.

Make sure all other instances of these browsers are closed when conducting this test.

When the problem doesn't exist when launched in safe mode you can remove all your extensions and add them in one by one to determine which extension is the culprit.

Sources:

[How to start firefox in safemode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677405/how-to-start-firefox-in-safemode)

https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off

Comment: I agree with your comment @elder-geek, still, I'm having the same issue on my machine. In between that, I'm also trying to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: @user132319 The answer I provided if followed should lead you to the extension that is causing the problem. Is there something about it that you don't understand? If so, let me know where you found it to be unclear and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

Long time lurker first time poster.

@Elder Geek

Thanks for your response to to @Tarun Mahajan question, malicious or misconfired extensions can cause this behavior but in this case your this is URL/code injection from the ISP.

How do I know?

- I am confident that @Tarun Mahajans ISP is BSNL/MTNL in India
- Got the redirects while using a live CD
- Tested the live CD at home, in the office, at a coffee shop all served by the same ISP
- Was unable to replicate results using another ISP ( Airtel )

@Tarun Mahajan can you share your ISPs' name?

naganoadigei.com was registered explicitly to serve malware and redirect users to phishing sites

Updated Date: 2018-05-10
Created Date: 2018-05-10

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. I have a bsnl connection and I keep getting occasional redirects to the above-said URL in my macos chrome browser. sometimes even in my android chrome browser. Any solutions yet?

Comment: Darn it I also have same issue and YES my ISP is BSNL.

Comment: Lot of discussion on this going on here: https://broadbandforum.co/threads/bsnl-broadband-ad-injection-random-redirection-to-malware-websites.169151

Comment: @naganoadigei.com my ISP is BSNL with dynamic IP.

Comment: Same here with BSNL connection.